# SDE Table Vs Query Table in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, sql

I have two SQL table with same columns/field name, but when I open both tables in ArcMap it shows different information in Source Tab.

[image]
SDE table type shows all of the fields where query table type missing one field in ArcMap though all same field I can see from SQL Server end.

I am using ArcMap 10.2 also I checked in pro and same thing is happening.

I'd like to know

- How I can change Query Table to SDE table.
- Any idea why two identical tables with field name, one showing all field and 
  other one is missing which is Date type column?

Comment: In most contexts, the difference between a Query Table and an SDE Table is rather fine. You've removed so much information that it is quite difficult to judge how these objects were created.  Usually ArcGIS doesn't let you use the table at all if the type on one column is unsupported.

Comment: So here what happens...In ArcMap , when i bring SDE type table from connections to layer window i don't get any pop ups and i can see all fields which i wanted to see. When i bring query type table, then i get pop up window 'New query Layer window' when i hit finish it adds to the Layer and then i am not able to see all fields basically one column is missing which has date data type in sql.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide this information. As OP, your duty is to improve the question. The difference is that one of the two tables is registered with the geodatabase.

Comment: Thanks Vince.. seems like your suggestions worked very well. I did registered with geodatabase and i was able to see missing field.